# Struts 2 I am not able to pass

Tags: java, redirect, parameters, struts2, struts-action

I have a struts 2 that has an action that has to drive to another called "buscarProposta" leading a parameter, but page is giving error.

The action must pass the parameter is name = "produtor" type = "redirectAction".

```xml
<action name="consultarProposta" class="consultaPropostaLiberacaoComissaoAction" 
                                method="consultarProposta">
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/consultaPropostaLiberacaoComissao.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/listaProposta/listaProposta.jsp</result>
        <result name="produtor" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">/WEB-INF/pages/produtores/produtores.jsp</param>
            <param name="chaveNegocio">${chaveNegocio}</param>
        </result>
   </action>


    <action name="buscarProposta" class="buscarPropostaAction" method="buscarProposta">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/produtores/produtores.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/listaProposta/listaProposta.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: Use the different type of the result. Redirect type results use response to send redirect result code to the browser. If you didn't supply parameters in the url then it will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

> ```xml
>     <result name="produtor" type="redirectAction">
>         <param name="actionName">/WEB-INF/pages/produtores/produtores.jsp</param>
>         <param name="chaveNegocio">${chaveNegocio}</param>
>     </result>
> ```

You are redirecting to a JSP, while `redirectAction`, as the name suggests, is used to redirect to an action:

```xml
<result name="produtor" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">buscarProposta</param>
    <param name="chaveNegocio">${chaveNegocio}</param>
</result>
```

Otherwise...

[image]

Comment: Plus one for the illustrative part. :)

Comment: So I did it, and still can not pass parameter to another page.                                   this is the massage ---- "The page cannot be found 
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: use the namespace too, or put "/buscarProposta" if the namespace is /

Comment: like this - <param name="actionName">buscarProposta</param>
<param name="namespace">/</param>             
<param name="chaveNegocio">${chaveNegocio}</param>

Comment: Exactly. Do you still get 404 ? Does your package have namespace="/" ?